# Mulifactor Authentication for dummy Account Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

I have successfully logged in Cobrand and User and set up DAG. I am trying to add an account with FMFA, but I end up with the error response as shown below.

```
https://developer.api.yodlee.com:443/ysl/restserver/v1/providerAccounts?providerId=16445
```

## Credentials Param:

```
{ "loginForm" :  {
        "id": 16103,
        "forgetPasswordURL": "http://64.14.28.129/dag/index.do",
        "formType": "login",
        "row": [
          {
            "id": 150862,
            "label": "Catalog",
            "form": "0001",
            "fieldRowChoice": "0001",
            "field": [
              {
                "id": 65499,
                "name": "LOGIN",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "ibrahimHassan.site16445.1",
                "isOptional": false,
                "valueEditable": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 150863,
            "label": "Password",
            "form": "0001",
            "fieldRowChoice": "0002",
            "field": [
              {
                "id": 65500,
                "name": "PASSWORD",
                "type": "password",
                "value": "site16445.1",
                "isOptional": false,
                "valueEditable": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
      }
```

## ProviderId : ***`16445`***

## Response:

```
{
  "errorCode": "Y400",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid value for login, site [DagSiteTokenFMPA]",
  "referenceCode": "f1493111410473e4L27n"
}
```

I need the response returned by this service so that I can model my iOS Application accordingly. If someone points out the APIs to hit in the correct order and the parameters for the API body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your request we can see the login form is not right. Please find the right login form-

Hope this helps.

```
{
    "loginForm": {
        "id": 16126,
        "forgetPasswordURL": "http://64.14.28.129/dag/index.do",
        "formType": "login",
        "row": [
          {
            "id": 150876,
            "label": "Catalog",
            "form": "0001",
            "fieldRowChoice": "0001",
            "field": [
              {
                "id": 65513,
                "name": "LOGIN",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "ibrahimHassan.site16445.1",
                "isOptional": false,
                "valueEditable": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 150877,
            "label": "Password",
            "form": "0001",
            "fieldRowChoice": "0002",
            "field": [
              {
                "id": 65514,
                "name": "PASSWORD",
                "type": "password",
                "value": "site16445.1",
                "isOptional": false,
                "valueEditable": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
}
```